# Mysql how to insert none or all rows - Revert all inserted in-case of error

Tags: mysql

Is there any built in way in mysql in which it either inserts all the given rows, or reverts all inserted rows if an error(eg duplicate error) occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to is commonly called a transaction.  You should begin a transaction and perform a series of inserts and rollback upon failure.

See [this document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) for further details on transactions.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword you are looking for is [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html).